# iOS Facebook read and publish likes

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I have seen [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes) documentation, but it asks for object-id to get number of like, it seems pretty simple but I am wondering for some time, how to get/know object-id of my object/thing?

**Edit:**
I am using this code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{object-id}/likes"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

What is `{object-id}` here ?

Comment: Please be a little more specific about your problem. Provide some code, etc...

Comment: done, kindly have a look

Comment: What are you trying to get the number of likes for? A Page? An OG action? Something else?

Comment: I have few custom objects, I want my app users to like that custom object , and then on respective objects I want 'like-count'

Comment: If you know it's a custom object, you should know the ID as well. Can you give an example of what you mean by custom-object here so we're all on the same page here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my object-id in Object browser, I was able to create object there, object id was also present there.